# What user does cPanel run a cron job as?

Tags: cron, cpanel

From what I've read, people are saying it runs it as the user under which the cron job is running.  However, this does not seem to be the case.  I have GPG set up on my server and have a script that unencrypts data, generates XML, encrypts the XML using someone else's public key, then sends it off to them.  If I run the script myself from the web I have no issues.  If I have my cron job run the script, I get issues saying that the directory holding the public key does not exist (which of course it does).  The owner of the folder is `nobody`.  If I `chmod` the folder permissions to `777` it works (of course) and runs just fine, but then I get the error `gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir` which is a given.  So I'm wondering what user this is running as so I can just change the ownership of the folder instead of the permissions.  If it is not the website owner under who's cPanel account the cron job has been set up, then what user would that be?

Comment: Did you ever find it out? (I know it's been almost 10 years lol)